# Strange error when opening Package for writing

Tags: c#, .net, package

First things first, I'm using .NET 4.

I'm trying to write some files to a package, and I'm encountering something strange when I do this:

```
using (var package = Package.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
    // do something with package
}
```

`Package` refers to [`System.IO.Packaging.Package`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms571902.aspx).

The weird thing is that Package.Open method throws an exception that says:

> Cannot get stream with FileMode.Create, FileMode.CreateNew, FileMode.Truncate, FileMode.Append when access is FileAccess.Read.

I found an old bug report from 2009 on Microsoft Connect:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/392318/argumentexception-text-is-wrong

But it doesn't help.

So, anyone got an idea?

Comment: Seems that you dont have the appropriate permissions here ..

Comment: @Akram The funny part is that a 0 byte file ends up being created at `filename`.

Comment: Does it work if you used FileAccess.Read ?

Comment: @Akram Nope, same error. But I doubt that will work, considering I'm trying to write to the file...

Comment: I know it sounds silly. Try FileAccess.Create this time ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I found the problem.

When I changed to code to do this:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (var package = Package.Open(stream))
    {
        // do something with package
    }
}
```

I got a pretty decent error message:

> Cannot open package because FileMode or FileAccess value is not valid for the stream.

I think that's the "real" error message, and that someone, somewhere, simply mixed it up with that nonsensical one when doing the localization.

Then I changed the code for this:

```
// no FileAccess parameter
using (var package = Package.Open(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    // do something with package
}
```

And it no longer crashes, and seems to work properly.

Comment: That's strange. Good catch, though.

Comment: +1 Leaving off the file-access parameter seems to solve it for me as well.  Sure glad I found your posts!  I was all set to have a long evening working on this one...